# Send different objects to different users from one base object Game

Tags: java, json

I have object `Game` which has ArrayList of `Player`s and some other info.

Right now I am sending whole `Game` object with it's properties as JSON to all the users.

What I want to achieve is this:

I have a very big structure btw so the players have heroes and heroes have some attributes and so on...

There are some info in `Player` class which I don't want to send to all the users (like `respawnTime` of a `Player` if he's not in your team.).

What is the best way to do this? I don't have any idea how to solve this problem...

Btw I use `Jackson` to transform a `Game` object to JSON.

Comment: I think you can use JsonNode, It has a lot of APIs that can do work that you want like:findValue, findPath and get methods .

Comment: Show the code you tried so far.

Comment: Sounds like the jolt library (https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) may be a solution.